# Multiple IF statement; Months

Tags: java, if-statement

I know this might be a really stupid question and I know I should import a class for this, but I would really like to know what is the mistake in the following code. I am taking Java class and I would really like to get some help.

```
int m = 1;
 String month;
        if(int m = 1){ 
           month = "January";
        }else if(int m = 2){ 
           month  = "February";   
        }else if(int m = 3){ 
           month  = "March"; 
        }else if(int m = 4){ 
           month  = "April"; 
        }else if(int m = 5){ 
           month  = "May"; 
        }else if(int m = 6){ 
           month  = "June"; 
        }else if(int m = 7){ 
           month  = "July";
        }else if(int m = 8){ 
           month  = "August";
        }else if(int m = 9){ 
           month  = "September"; 
        }else if(int m = 10){ 
           month  = "October"; 
        }else if(int m = 11){ 
           month  = "November"; 
        }else if(int m = 12){ 
           month  = "December"; 
        }
```

I keep getting

```
*./Root/Main.java:16: error: '.class' expected
        if(int m = 1){ 
               ^*
```

Is the problem with the string name?

Comment: Next time, please go to the http://codereview.stackexchange.com site which is more appropriate for those kind of questions. Also, I think you are being downvoted because there are plenty of existing resources already, including this site, where you could have found an answer by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I am new here and well, you know what noobs do....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is re-defining the variable `m`. The comparison should read as follows: `if (m == 1)`. The corrected code would be:

```
int m = 1;
String month;
if(m == 1){ 
    month = "January";
}else if(m == 2){ 
    month  = "February";   
}else if(m == 3){ 
   month  = "March"; 
}else if(m == 4){ 
   month  = "April"; 
}else if(m == 5){ 
   month  = "May"; 
}else if(m == 6){ 
   month  = "June"; 
}else if(m == 7){ 
   month  = "July";
}else if(m == 8){ 
   month  = "August";
}else if(m == 9){ 
   month  = "September"; 
}else if(m == 10){ 
   month  = "October"; 
}else if(m == 11){ 
   month  = "November"; 
}else if(m == 12){ 
   month  = "December"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to define a new integer variable m inside the if condition. 
You should do this:

```
int m = 1;
String month;
if( m == 1)
{ 
       month = "January";
}
```

etc. Note i have removed the int, and changed = to == (ie equality check, rather than assignment)

Answer (score 1):

`=` is assignment operation, `==` is equality comparison operator.
change `if(int m = 1){`  to `if(int m =＝ 1){`

If you want to get rid of multiple if-else statements, my suggestion is:

```
int m = 1;
String month = "";

// stores months names in order
String[] months = {"January", "February", "March"....}
// gets the corresponding name by index
month = months[m-1];
```

Comment: I would rather store `months` as a final static class member instead of defining it as a local variable in the function. I may be wrong, but I don't think Java compilers do recognize that `months` is in fact a constant and avoid allocating it each time the function is called.

Comment: `Enum Month` is the best

Answer (score 1):

## Why .class?

The reason the `.class` is expected is because Java expects to find a value where you provided the `int` type. Types are however not usable as values.

The only possible way where it makes sense to have a value starting with `int` is when we access its `.class` attribute: the compiler assumes you wanted to do that.

## Inline declaration

There are places where you can put inline variable declarations, like in `for` loops. What follows an `if` is supposed to be an expression, so declarations are forbidden.

## Use an equality `==` operator

Otherwise, you will assign the right-hand side (LHS) of the `=` to `m`, which is not what you want.

## Do not use so many `if`

Since you are using integers, you can easily use a switch statement:

```
switch (m) {
case 1: month="January"; break;
case 2: month="February"; break;
...
}
```

Switches over a range of integers in the form `a..b` are generally compiled as direct access, much like if you used an array.
Of course, you can also define a static final array of months and access it using `m` as the index.

*Edit*: Quite interestingly, the example for the `switch` statement in [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) is dealing with your exact problem.

## Enum Month

You said it, "I should import a class for this", and effectively, as kindly hinted by [haifzan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493257/multiple-if-statement-months/30493446?noredirect=1#comment49065049_30493446), you only need to use the [existing enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html).